# The key moved too slow when test with https://qual-e.appspot.com

Tags: cobalt

When test with https://qual-e.appspot.com with cobalt rc_11 version, the key move too slow(5s+), sometimes the focus even can not move at all, it's hard to test with the page, after checking with the cpu usage, the MainWebModule used 98% CPU, so is there any way to improve it?

1> CPU usage of MainWebModule is 98% when move the focus

[image: CPU Usage]

2> The trace log of when move the focus

[image: What's the MainWebModule doing?]

3> the call backtrace of UpdateComputedStylesAndLayoutBoxTree

```
[cobalt]>       cobalt::layout::UpdateComputedStylesAndLayoutBoxTree() [0xcad0a0]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::layout::LayoutManager::Impl::DoSynchronousLayout() [0xc919b4]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::Document::DoSynchronousLayout() [0x2c3fe8]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::HTMLElement::offset_width() [0x2ec704]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::(anonymous namespace)::get_offsetWidth() [0xecf80c]
[cobalt]>       js::Invoke() [0xa55a60]
[cobalt]>       js::Invoke() [0xa56348]
[cobalt]>       js::InvokeGetter() [0xa564e0]
[cobalt]>       js::BaseProxyHandler::get() [0x9ee84c]
[cobalt]>       js::Proxy::get() [0x9f47f0]
[cobalt]>       js::GetProperty() [0xa45c74]
[cobalt]>       Interpret() [0xa4b578]
[cobalt]>       js::RunScript() [0xa557c8]
[cobalt]>       js::Invoke() [0xa55b24]
[cobalt]>       js::Invoke() [0xa56348]
[cobalt]>       JS::Call() [0x931614]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::MozjsEventListener::HandleEvent() [0xeb448c]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::EventListener::HandleEvent() [0x338e30]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::EventTarget::FireEventOnListeners() [0x2d7e40]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::Node::DispatchEvent() [0x3100fc]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::dom::Window::InjectEvent() [0x322e80]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::browser::WebModule::Impl::InjectInputEvent() [0x850ac]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::browser::WebModule::Impl::InjectKeyboardEvent() [0x863d0]
[cobalt]>       base::internal::Invoker<>::Run() [0x8db04]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::RunTask() [0xc1e3c]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask() [0xc2c50]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::DoWork() [0xc3994]
[cobalt]>       base::MessagePumpDefault::Run() [0xc8ca8]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::RunInternal() [0xc4ca8]
[cobalt]>       base::RunLoop::Run() [0xd9438]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::Run() [0xc1708]
[cobalt]>       base::Thread::ThreadMain() [0xf4df0]
[cobalt]>       base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0xf2984]
[cobalt]>       (anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x11525c]
```

4>focus move backtrace in Youtube(the same cobalt binary, no this issue)

```
[cobalt]>       cobalt::layout::UpdateComputedStylesAndLayoutBoxTree() [0xcad0a0]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::layout::Layout() [0xcae0cc]
[cobalt]>       cobalt::layout::LayoutManager::Impl::DoLayoutAndProduceRenderTree() [0xc929d4]
[cobalt]>       base::Timer::RunScheduledTask() [0xf6b40]
[cobalt]>       base::BaseTimerTaskInternal::Run() [0xf6f54]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::RunTask() [0xc1e3c]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask() [0xc2c50]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::DoDelayedWork() [0xc2d80]
[cobalt]>       base::MessagePumpDefault::Run() [0xc8ccc]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::RunInternal() [0xc4ca8]
[cobalt]>       base::RunLoop::Run() [0xd9438]
[cobalt]>       MessageLoop::Run() [0xc1708]
[cobalt]>       base::Thread::ThreadMain() [0xf4df0]
[cobalt]>       base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0xf2984]
[cobalt]>       (anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x11525c]
[cobalt]>       <unknown> [0xb6612e84]
[cobalt]>       <unknown> [0xb6612e84]
```

Comment: I will check it out.

Comment: Works well on qa build. Which build type did you test with?

Comment: hi, daniel, both qa build & gold build can reproduce it.

Comment: hi, dnaiel, so is there any suggestions that we can check that why the focus moving is  too slow?

Comment: hi, daniel, I got a trace log when moved the focus, you can see the MainWebModule thread was keep doing Layout about every 15.167ms, which may cause the cpu loading to high and no response with the key.

Comment: hi, dnaiel, after adding some logs, it seemed the cobalt::layout::UpdateComputedStylesAndLayoutBoxTree() is called from the js in the test page, so is it the issue of the page itself?

Comment: I just reproduced it. We will investigate this issue.

Comment: hi daniel, I just moved this issue to the issue tracker page for better discussion & tracing, please help to reference it, thank you. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64012090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed at Cobalt 11.78008 https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/810d1764791f7924402f1686ea98ed36ff8b36cb

It was caused by the mixture of Qual-E focus manager logic and Cobalt layout manager logic. We enhanced the layout manager logic by decoupling laying out box tree and generating render tree.